# Python print function

Tags: python, printing, python-3.x

I began learning Python a little time ago, and I got the first problem. Here's the code:

```
fh = open('/usr/share/dict/words')
for line in fh.readlines():
    print(line, end='')
```

When I execute it in the Terminal (OS X), it tells me `invalid syntax` error where `end` equal sign is placed. What's the problem here? Didn't find the solution...

I installed Python 3.3.0 from this [page](http://python.org/download), Python 3.3.0 Mac OS X 64-bit/32-bit x86-64/i386 Installer

Sorry for so nooby questions :(

Comment: How are you running this code (like the command in Terminal)? It's being run with OS X's Python, not the one you installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Python 3 installer does not make Python 3 the default Python (if it did, it would break a ton of stuff, because very few Python scripts are Python 3 compatible). So to get Python 3, you should execute your script as `python3 script.py`, or add `#!/usr/bin/env python3` to the top of the file.

Comment: If I had more votes left you'd get one. Did not know about the hashbang. Thanks.

Comment: It works with `python3 script.py` but how can I make Python 3 the default Python? Hashbang is not helping.

Comment: @Randex: You can modify `PATH` in your `.profile` script, or alias `python=python3` (also in `.profile`). That way, you get Python 3 on the command line, but the system Python stays at Python 2 for compatibility.

Comment: So I just write `python=python3` in it?

Comment: If you use alias, when you type `python` you'll get python 3, but scripts that use `/usr/bin/env python` will still get python 2, which is probably the best.

Answer (score 6):

Your terminal is probably using Python2.x

Try using the command `python3 yourfilename.py`

To see which Python version is the standard on your terminal just type `python`

You should see something like this:

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

To make your code work with 2.x you can use print without the parantheses:

```
print "Python", "yay!"
```

Comment: Note you can't exactly replicate `end=''` on Python 2 (unless you use `sys.stdout`. A trailing comma will result in an extra space on the next output.

Comment: True, and why I changed the arguments. Shouldn't have glossed over it.